# Select one of three numbers with equal probability?

Tags: java, random

I would like to select one of three numbers with equal probability (33.3%). Can I use the `Random` class to achieve this?

What would be the percentage of each number being selected after 100x running? Would it be evenly 33.3% each?

Comment: deterministic pseudorandom or non-deterministic?
Or do you mean you need uniformly distributed random numbers?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.0randomNumberGenerator

Comment: So your question isn't "How does Random work?", but rather "How can I have a function that selects one of three numbers with exactly equal probability?" ?

Comment: It will be even probability unless you make it otherwise

Comment: @Stefan, I'm not so familiar with those terms. Yes I want uniformly/evenly distributed numbers.

Comment: @Duncan, Yes it is. :)

Comment: @Gautham, so by default it will evenly picked 33.3%?

Comment: @Halim, in the long run. And it will not be in a round robin style. This means, you can have `1` potentially picked up 20 (or 30, or 1000) times in a row.

Comment: @Halim I've tried to edit your question to reflect what you appear to be asking.

Comment: @Duncan, Yes that is definitely what I meant. Thanks for your edit. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Random.nextInt(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method to select a number between `0` and `2`. Use this to choose one of your three values.

```
int index = Random.nextInt(3);
int selectedValue = myOptions[index];
```

The value returned by that method is uniformly distributed. So if you were to repeat this process infinitely, the probability of each number being chosen would approach 1/3.

From the docs:

> All `n` possible `int` values are produced with **(approximately) equal probability**

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethin like this for 1/25 probabilty

```
if(new java.util.Random().nextInt(25)==0){
//Do something.
}
```

Comment: A strange example, given the OP is looking for 1/3 probability.

Comment: @Kamlesh Can you please explain about it?

Comment: @Octopus..sorry about the late reply..the example as i gave will generate random number between [1,25] with each number having probability of 1/25

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int number = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

Note that there is no such thing as true random. In computer science, we use so called pseudo-randomness. For most everyday purposes that's close enough to random that the difference isn't noticable. You say you'll be running it 100 times, then yes. For all intents and purposes it will be 33.3333...%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether entropy is more important than 'randomnes'. Randomness will not give you a perfect 33.3% but the final outcome will be unpredictable. Other algorithms can give you a perfect 33.3% but the outcome can be predictable, and even the same in some cases each time the process is ran.

Comment: Which algorithms can give a perfect 33.3%? I suspect the OP would want to know.

Comment: @ClosetGeek, yes can you describe more on the technical point? How to make it unpredictable and how to make it perfect 33.3%?

Comment: @Halim I'll get more in-depth but it will take a while. In short, by expecting 33.3% your in effect expecting a predictable outcome which doesn't work when something's truly random. For a perfect 33.3% you'll want to use a shuffle algorithm. I'll look that up as well.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible for exact random ness for only a two value range.
....after random statemeants...

```
if(rand=>1&&rand<=1.4999999999999999999999....)

{

rand=1;

}

else

{

rand=2

}
```